# Javascript Closures, same parameters, but it prints out a different answer

Tags: javascript

How come when I run console.log(action(8)) twice its gives me the answer 1108 and 2108?
Shouldn't it be 1108 & 1108?

```
var counter = 100;   //line 1

function make(){
    var local = 1000;
    return function(x){
        temp = local;
        local *= 2;
        return x + counter + temp;
    }
}

var action = make();

console.log(action(8)); // 1108
console.log(action(8)); // 2108
```

Comment: Oh dear, what happened to the indentation and line feeds?

Comment: for that you have to get independent actions like bellow... `var action1 = make();
var action2 = make();

console.log(action1(8));
console.log(action2(8));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because `local` changes every time you call it.

The whole point of a closure is to capture the variables in the outer function.

Comment: So the second time the console.log(action(8)) runs, local = 1108?

Comment: No, it will be 2000 because you double it each time.

Comment: In your code, you have a line that reads `local *= 2`. I'm not sure if you really understand the assignment operators but it is equivalent to: `local = local*2`. If local was 1000 and you multiply it by 2 each time then the second time you call it local is 2000 so the result is obviously 2108. The third time you call it it will be 4108, then 8108, 16108 etc.